# HttpServlerRequest in iphone

Tags: iphone, http, ipad

i am a newb in http request. is it possible to request httpservletrequest in iphone sdk if it give me some sample code for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right, but for simple HTTP requests I like to use [ASIHTTPRequest wrapper](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

You'll find sources, samples and getting started guide by a link above.